# Openlayers Geojson axios API Get data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, openlayers, geojson

I want to get data(geojson format) from my API on the localhost and based on the read data, present the markers on the map.

GeoJson format:

```
{
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        53.531697,
                        23.545435
                    ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "Shop_Id": 328,
                    "Shop_Name": "A01_0386,4_TF_0",
                    "Shop_Radius": 0.1512987687
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        29.54306,
                        31.531401
                    ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "Shop_Id": 532,
                    "Shop_Name": "A01_0397,0_TF_0",
                    "Shop_Radius": 0.1773436375047
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        28.34949,
                        30.10745
                    ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "Shop_Id": 160,
                    "Shop_Name": "A01_0003,9_TF_0",
                    "Shop_Radius": 0.1922466020678
                }
            }
]
}
```

When I read this from geojson file it shows up properly on map, but if I want to get data from API:
http://localhost:8080/get_shops, then I can't reach these markers.

My logic:

```
var styles = {
    'Point': new Style({
        stroke: new Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(17,158,76,0.8)',//#F3C35D
            width: 15,
        })
    })

}

var styleFunction = function(feature) {
    return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
};

var vectorSource = new VectorSource({
    format: new GeoJSON(),
    loader: vectorLoader(),
    projection:"EPSG:4326",

})

function vectorLoader(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/get_shops'
        ,{
            "dataType": 'json',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type":"application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
                "crossorigin":true
            }
        }
    )
        .then(res => {
            console.log("1: " + JSON.stringify(res.data));
            console.log("1: " + JSON.stringify(res.data[0]));
            var geoJsonFormat = new GeoJSON();
            var features = geoJsonFormat.readFeatures(JSON.stringify(res.data));
            vectorSource.addFeatures(features)
            // return JSON.stringify(res.data[0]);

        })
        .catch(err => console.warn(err))
}


var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: styleFunction
});


const map = new Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM()
        }),vectorLayer],
        view: new View({
    center: fromLonLat([12,44]) ,
    zoom: 3,
})
});
```

and Error:

```
Error: Unsupported GeoJSON type: undefined
    readGeometry GeoJSON.js:295
    readFeatureFromObject GeoJSON.js:110
    readFeaturesFromObject GeoJSON.js:144
    readFeatures JSONFeature.js:52
    vectorLoader Mapper.js:110
```

I want to use Axios than jQuery because I've received an error with $ is no defined.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Which `console.log` call shows the correct data?  Whichever is correct there is no need to stringify the data, the parser can handle an object - but you will need to transform the features to map projection  `var features = geoJsonFormat.readFeatures(res.data, {featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection()});`

Comment: The correct data shows JSON.stringify(res.data[0]) ; this [0] because from external sites I've got quadratic brackets. I add this featureProjection but this is not working.

Comment: So you will also need to use `res.data[0]` in the `readFeatures` call.

Comment: Yea I try with all combinations but still not working. Maybe I forgot some important aspect? Could You show me solution in codepen or something like this ?

Comment: If your console.log shows geojson data it is likely that there is something missing in the data, such as a geometry or geometry type, as the error suggests.  Can you include the log output in the question?

Answer (score 0):

This is my output from console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data[0])):

```
{
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        53.531697,
                        23.545435
                    ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "Shop_Id": 328,
                    "Shop_Name": "A01_0386,4_TF_0",
                    "Shop_Radius": 0.1512987687
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        29.54306,
                        31.531401
                    ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "Shop_Id": 532,
                    "Shop_Name": "A01_0397,0_TF_0",
                    "Shop_Radius": 0.1773436375047
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        28.34949,
                        30.10745
                    ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "Shop_Id": 160,
                    "Shop_Name": "A01_0003,9_TF_0",
                    "Shop_Radius": 0.1922466020678
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        18.34949,
                        26.10745
                    ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "Shop_Id": 1340,
                    "Shop_Name": "F01_0032,9_TF_0",
                    "Shop_Radius": 0.1922443220678
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        72.339,
                        20.1545
                    ]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "Shop_Id": 210,
                    "Shop_Name": "G32_0003,9_TF_0",
                    "Shop_Radius": 0.1925346020678
                }
            }
]
}
```

Comment: The data is good.  Your problem is likely to be because you are running the loader function `loader: vectorLoader(),` instead of specifying the function `loader: vectorLoader,` in the source constructor.  Also a Stroke style alone will not style Point geometries, but you can use it to outline a regular shape or circle style https://codesandbox.io/s/geojson-027t9.